# Multi span in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i am using Bootstrap 2 to design my webpage. In my web page i am designing a filmstrip which initially shows 5 images and on click it shows next 5 images an so on..

My question is that, i have to keep all the images in a row of width greater than 1800px. The width should be auto adjusted based on its contents and when i make window size small the filmstrip show show only 4 and on further shrink of window it should show 3, 2 and 1.

is there any way to achieve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: Yes i have a working model of it. i have placed my filmstrip in my Bootstrap container. When i shrink my window the items are getting hide(half of image will be shown) which is not responsive, rater it should show only 4 or 3.

Comment: Could you post your code here ?